# show that some differential operator has infinitely many eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=C(-\infty,\infty)$ be the set of all functions such that the nth derivative is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T(f(x)) = -2f''(x)-2f'(x)$
>
> show that T has infinitely many eigenvalues.

This is my solution. Is it correct?
Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\text{ such that }\alpha \neq 0$
To find the eigenvalues, we set
$$T(f(x))=\alpha f(x)$$
Substituting $T(f(x))$ gives:
$$-f''(x)-2f'(x)=\alpha f(x)$$
The solution to this differential equation is of the form $c_1e^{\lambda_1x}+c_2e^{\lambda_2x}$, where $\lambda_{1,2}=-1\pm \sqrt{1-\alpha}$

Now,

$\alpha=1 \implies \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = -1 \implies f(x)=c_1 e^{-x}\implies E_{\alpha=1}=span({e^{-x}})$
$\alpha<1 \implies \lambda_{1,2} \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x)=c_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}+c_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x}\implies E_{\alpha<1}=span({e^{-\lambda_1 x},e^{- \lambda_2 x}})$
$\alpha>1 \implies \lambda_{1,2} \in \mathbb{C} \implies f(x)=c_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}+c_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x}\implies E_{\alpha>1}=span (e^{-\lambda_1 x},e^{- \lambda_2 x})$

Therefore, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R},~ \exists f(x)\text{ such that }T(f(x))=\alpha(x)$. Hence, T has infinitely many eigenvalues.

Comment: The solutions to the differential equation are not correct. This part needs a small modification. Nevertheless, you proved that any non-zero real number is an eigenvalue. So, your solution is correct.

Comment: why aren't they correct?

Comment: For instance, if the characteristic equation has a double root (case $\alpha = 1$), the solution is $f(x) = (c_1 + c_2x)e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks @BolzWeir. Is this the only solution I missed?

Comment: You're welcome. No, you missed the second and the third as well. This is a useful reference: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx